# pandas color column based on value of other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, background-color

I want to make a conditional formatting, which is applied on another column in a pandas dataframe. So I want to change the font-color to blue in columns " timestart" and "timeend", if value in columns "mark_start", "mark_end" is greater than 0. I used below code but i need to color another column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lst = [['Load from table main', '2023-08-02 01:33:47' , 1, '2023-08-02 02:33:47' , 0],
       ['Load from table output', '2023-08-01 02:34:57' , 0, '2023-08-02 02:33:47' , 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['comment','timestart','mark_start','timeend','mark_end'])
col_background_name = ['mark_start','mark_end']
col_val = ['timestart','timeend']

def highlight_col_val(col):
    if col.name in col_background_name:
        return ['background-color:blue' if val == 1 else '' for val in col]
    else:
        return ['' for _ in col]
           
st = df.style.apply(highlight_col_val, axis=0)
st.to_excel("out.xlsx",engine='openpyxl')
```

The value of the 'mark_start' column refers to the 'timestart' column, and the value of the 'mark_end' column refers to the 'timeend' column.

I attempted to do this by doing the following, but it doesn't work

```
def highlight_col_val_three(col,col_val):
    if col.name in col_background_name:
        return ['background-color:blue' if val == 1 and col == col_val else '' for val in col]
    else:
        return ['' for _ in col]

st = df.style.apply(highlight_col_val_three, axis=0)
```

I need to pass two parameters ['mark_start','timestart'] with values ​​to a function def highlight_col_val_three.
How to do it i don't know

I've explored the style.apply approaches, but can't seem to find one that works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I attempted to do this by doing the following, but it doesn't work

```
def highlight_col_val_three(col,col_val):
    if col.name in col_background_name:
        return ['background-color:blue' if val == 1 and col == col_val else '' for val in col]
    else:
        return ['' for _ in col]

st = df.style.apply(highlight_col_val_three, axis=0)
```